# Accidently deleted ssl in Puppet Master

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I accidentally deleted SSL and now there is nothing inside my /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests/. I have tried re-installing puppet master and done few other things but it hasn't solved yet.

Is there a way to get the certificates back without having to re-configure puppet master again and doing all the steps?

Comment: If you know have backup on the ssl folder in puppet master, then the answer is "NO".

Comment: Really, the `certificate_requests` directory is the least of your worries.  If you deleted the whole `ssl/` directory then you deleted the master's host and CA certificates, and without those you are thoroughly hosed.  Recover from backup (you *do* have backups, right?).

Comment: Looks like magically I am okay. I have ssl directory now(it's in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl), and whenever I pass the certificates to the new hosts I am configuring now, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Check if the old hosts can run puppet also. Most probably you will need to redo the certificates for those ones.

Comment: Spot on. Did that. I had to pass the certificates to the ones I deleted.Now it's fine. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Run `puppet agent --test` on clients. It will generate new certificate and request to the puppet master.
On puppet master you will get new request from client. Check out new request using command `puppet cert list` and sign the request with `puppet cert sign $cert_name`

[Reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.4.2/man/cert.html)